# How To Turn Main Code Into A Class (Snowfall)

Tags: java, arrays, class, processing, processing.js

I'm working on trying to use this free source code I found (http://solemone.de/demos/snow-effect-processing/) into a class that I can utilize within a larger, more complex "game" code. It's a pretty basic snow fall code:

```
int quantity = 15;
float [] xPosition = new float[quantity];
float [] yPosition = new float[quantity];
int [] flakeSize = new int[quantity];
int [] direction = new int[quantity];
int minFlakeSize = 10;
int maxFlakeSize = 20;

void setup() {

  size(800, 350);
  frameRate(30);
  noStroke();
  smooth();

  for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    flakeSize[i] = round(random(minFlakeSize, maxFlakeSize));
    xPosition[i] = random(0, width);
    yPosition[i] = random(0, height);
    direction[i] = round(random(0, 1));
  }

}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  for(int i = 0; i < xPosition.length; i++) {

    ellipse(xPosition[i], yPosition[i], flakeSize[i], flakeSize[i]);

    if(direction[i] == 0) {
      xPosition[i] += map(flakeSize[i], minFlakeSize, maxFlakeSize, .1, .5);
    } else {
      xPosition[i] -= map(flakeSize[i], minFlakeSize, maxFlakeSize, .1, .5);
    }

    yPosition[i] += flakeSize[i] + direction[i]; 

    if(xPosition[i] > width + flakeSize[i] || xPosition[i] < -flakeSize[i] || yPosition[i] > height + flakeSize[i]) {
      xPosition[i] = random(0, width);
      yPosition[i] = -flakeSize[i];
    }

  }

}
```

I just haven't quite grasped on how to separate the for() loops, integers, and arrays into functions I can put into a separate class that I've titled Snow so that I can easily move it and manipulate it within the greater code. Here's one of my (many) attempts so far:

Class Tab:

```
class Snow{


int quantity = 15;
float [] xPosition = new float[quantity];
float [] yPosition = new float[quantity];
int [] flakeSize = new int[quantity];
int [] direction = new int[quantity];
int minFlakeSize = 10;
int maxFlakeSize = 20;

 Snow(){
  frameRate(30);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
}

void display() {
    flakeSize = round(random(minFlakeSize, maxFlakeSize));
    xPosition = random(0, width);
    yPosition = random(0, height);
    direction = round(random(0, 1));
  }



void update() {

  for(int i = 0; i < xPosition.length; i++) {

    ellipse(xPosition[i], yPosition[i], flakeSize[i], flakeSize[i]);

    if(direction[i] == 0) {
      xPosition[i] += map(flakeSize[i], minFlakeSize, maxFlakeSize, .1, .5);
    } else {
      xPosition[i] -= map(flakeSize[i], minFlakeSize, maxFlakeSize, .1, .5);
    }

    yPosition[i] += flakeSize[i] + direction[i]; 

    if(xPosition[i] > width + flakeSize[i] || xPosition[i] < -flakeSize[i] || yPosition[i] > height + flakeSize[i]) {
      xPosition[i] = random(0, width);
      yPosition[i] = -flakeSize[i];
    }

  }

}
}
```

Main Tab:

```
//Ice
Snow [] flakes = new Snow[15];
int quantity = 15;

void setup(){
 size(600,800); 
 flakes = new Snow[15];

}

void draw(){
background(0);
for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++){
flakes[i].display();
flakes[i].update();
}

}
```

I'm sure it's a really simple method of breaking down the code and separating them into the proper places, but I can't seem to grasp it.
If anyone could help me with this process, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Uhhh this does not look like javascript...?

Comment: Oh! Sorry! It's Java in Processing.org. I accidentally put Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code doesn't make sense, because the `Snow` class seems to be keeping track of **every** snowflake, but you then have multiple instances of `Snow`.

Instead of trying to copy-paste random code into your sketch, you'll have **much** better luck if you take a step back, start a little smaller, try to understand what the code does, and then write your own code.

**Step 1:** Can you create a class that encapsulates the data and behavior for **a single snowflake**?

Don't worry about multiple snowflakes yet. Just get something very basic working. Here's a simple example class:

```
class SnowFlake{

  float x = random(width);
  float y = random(height);
  float r = random(10);

  void draw(){
   ellipse(x, y, r, r);

   y++;

   if(y > height){
     y = 0;
     x = random(width);
   }
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** Can you use that class in a **single variable** to draw a single snowflake?

You might create a little example sketch like this:

```
SnowFlake snowFlake;

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
  snowFlake = new SnowFlake();
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  snowFlake.draw();
}
```

Get this single snowflake working perfectly before moving on.

**Step 3:** Now that you have the single snowflake working, can you use an array or `ArrayList` to create multiple snowflakes?

If you work in small steps, it will be easy to add one thing at a time:

```
ArrayList<SnowFlake> snowFlakes = new ArrayList<SnowFlake>();

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    snowFlakes.add(new SnowFlake());
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (SnowFlake snowFlake : snowFlakes) {
    snowFlake.draw();
  }
}
```

[image]

You can't program by trying to blindly copy-paste code into your sketch. You have to really understand what it's doing, and you're usually better off just writing your own code based on that understanding. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Kevin! I honestly wanted to create my own code from the start, but I had no idea where to begin with it. I was hoping borrowing code would get me on a better path, but it only ended up confusing things even more for me. I really appreciate your in depth response. I currently have a problem understanding the basic java code process at the moment, and explanations like yours really help me figure things out a little more. Thank you very much!